# Install tuleap on amazon ec2 linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum, amazon-ami

I'd like to know if it's possible to install tuleap on amazon ec2 linux ami.
I searched the net unsuccessfully and when I try to install tuleap with yum, I got confilcts error (with httpd24, php55-common,...)

I tried to remove the conflicting packages but the error is still the same...

Anyone had a successfull feedback of tuleap installation on amazon?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From https://tuleap.net/site/ : "New ! Generic questions and answers from and by the community are on the Stack Exchange websites. 
 If the question is about how to use, configure, set-up, connect or do anything with Tuleap, it's proper place is on superuser.com"

Comment: Thanks for the advise, the question has been posted here : http://superuser.com/questions/812692/install-tuleap-on-amazon-ec2-linux-ami